# External link with Bootstrap 3 Tabs using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using tabs with Twitter Bootstrap 3 and want one of them to function as an external link that opens a new window. I removed the `data-toggle="tab"` and added some JQuery to accomplish this. The code below doesn't work and gives me the following error message, however if I add `class="active"` to the `li` element, it works perfectly (other than that tab having incorrect styling). Why is this the case? How can I alter my code so I don't need `class="active"` on the parent `li`?:

[image]

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="external-link" target="_blank">
        <span class="nav-text-wrapper">Example Tab Name</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.external-link').click(function(){
  window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

EDIT:
I found the solution. I had the following JQuery code to allow for nested tabs, but apparently this conflicted with me using external links on tabs

```
var $mainTabs = $('.tab-menu a');
$mainTabs.click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Comment: try adding e to your function and e.preventDefault(); inside the function.

Comment: Is the code that I added to the edited section of my post what you meant? If so, it still isn't working. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you even need the javascript? It seems like the link by itself is enough to open the link in a new window.

Comment: @Peter Apparently Bootstrap tabs remove normal functionality from links, so the link by itself does not work.

Comment: Also, how are you initializing the tabs? Are you using the `data-` attributes or some javascript? It looks like the exception is being thrown in the `show()` function but this shouldn't be called if you've removed that `data-toggle=tab` attribute.

Comment: Not using Javascript results in the same error: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://www.google.com/"

Comment: Any chance you could reproduce this in jsfiddle, codepen, or something? I tried to reproduce the problem here - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wabqYe - and didn't get any errors?

Comment: I'm using data-toggle="tab". A typical tab looks like the one above with data-toggle="tab" and without the target="_blank" and class="external-link"

Comment: @Peter I was using some code to allow for nested tabs, which Bootstrap doesn't support by deault. I deleted that code and my external link now works. I edited my post to include the code that was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$('a.external-link').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default tab selection behavior
  window.open($(this).attr('href')); 
});
```

`show.bs.tab` is an event that gets raised for a tab right before it is shown. By cancelling it with `e.preventDefault()`, you're interrupting the tab's `show()` function early on and inserting your own behavior. If you don't stop the `show()` function early like this, it will try to select the tab panel referenced in your `href` in order to show it. The error you were getting was because the tab plugin was trying to find a DOM element with a selector like this:   `$('https://www.google.com')`.

Comment: It worked! Would you mind explaining how that fixed the problem so I can understand?

Comment: Awesome! I just updated my answer with some explanation.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. Makes sense now.